# Developing a software module to access USPTO Private Pair for my firm

Tags: software, patent-applications, uspto, api, public-pair

I was told USPTO does not provide API for accessing their Private Pair data.

However, I understand that a few docking software available claim that they are access USPTO Private Pair with the right USPTO login.

I can't find any reference on how to develop a software module to access my firm's Private Pair. I am aiming to be able to allow the module to check my Private Pair as soon as a Private PAIR Correspondence Notification is received.

Is there any way to achieve this? Appreciate for any input. Thanks.

Comment: Probably not what you want, but there is this: https://developer.uspto.gov/api-catalog. And a Python library: https://pypi.org/project/uspto-opendata-python/

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I have looked into the above links, but they are for the public pair only.
Much appreciated. Hoping someone would show me some direction?

Comment: I converted you "answer" to a comment. StackExchange sites are strictly question and answer format and not a forum. As you gain reputation you get the ability to comment. Unfortunately, I don't have any more info to offer by you could reach out to the author of the Python library on Github: https://github.com/ip-tools/uspto-opendata-python

Comment: Otherwise, the question might be directed to Software Recommendation SE site as it is probably more appropriate there. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct way to do this through an API.  What you'll want to do is develop a crawler, either local (e.g., automate IE or Selenium) or cloud-based. As Private PAIR access requires passing 2-factor authentication from the uspto.gov website, you'll need to build that authentication process into your framework.  As a result, you'll need to wait for the user input or have some email configured on the server to receive/handle authentication messages from PTO before you can log-in.

Once you log-in to the internal  Pair page, then it's just a matter of automating clicks and moving through their website while collecting data or downloading documents. Either way, it's a quite a bit of work.  Also, the USPTO is always tweaking their site and actively trying to prevent bots from accessing it, so it's a project that will require constant updates.

You can also consider getting some commercial software that can do it.  For example:

ClaimMaster: https://www.patentclaimmaster.com/blog/tutorial-downloading-documents-from-pair/

Pair Downloader: https://www.neustelsoftware.com/pairdownloader/